# Create entries option is disabled in SE11. Why?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

Hi I am new to ABAP and I would like some guidance on how to create a table and also add the database items.

I created one transparent table.
made data elements and domains for each field, I was given a warning error message stating:
[Specify a client - specific application table] then it was saved and activated.

But when I go to Utilities --> TABLE CONTENTS --> there CREATE ENTRIES has been disabled.
And on the Delivery and Maintenance tab, I have set Data Browser/Table View Maint. to Allow it.

I'm stuck and I am not able to select create entries. Is there another way to do this?

Ultimately, I am trying to enter the data into the database. And I keep getting the [Specify a client- specific application table] All help Greatly Appreciated…

[image: SE11 Utilities Table Contents]

[image: edits made from comment]

[image: edits made from comments]

Here I changed the order of my key fields and then I selected the Delivery & Maintenance tab verified Data Browser- Display/ Maintenance Allowed. Now the create entries drop-down is still inactive.

[image]

Comment: Only the top columns of the table can be part of the primary key (checkbox in the second column). The client column (data type `CLNT`) should be the first key field, and you should move the columns Material Type and Material Group above the Material Description (and eventually above Material if it's not defined as a key field).

Comment: @SandraRossi Thank you for helping me with my table. I will make those adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

You should change maintenance access level on `Delivery and maintenance` tab

[image]

to **Maintenance allowed**.

More than likely your current setup is *Maintenance allowed with restrictions*.

Comment: thank you for your input. I already have that selected but it's still not allowing me to create entries.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. I kept receiving error messages about having a space in the field name section. After making those corrections I was able to select create entries from the drop-down menu.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. What means "a space in the field name section"? NB: if there's a syntax error, you cannot activate the table, i.e. you can't play with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to drop down menu GOTO >> TECHNICAL SETTINGS ()

Once on this screen Select your data class and size category.

Save this and activate your table.

You should no longer get the message "Specify a client - specific application table" and should be able to insert entries.